# How to trigger an action when deleting value from an autocomplete field on Apex 18.2

Tags: oracle-apex-18.2

I have created an autocomplete item on my page and i want to trigger the change on this field. I am using Apex 18.2 and for the autocomplete item i have used a dynamic action with event Update [Text field with autocomplete]. 
This works fine when i change the value from the autocomplete and put another value from the list, but if i want to delete the value, the DA is not triggered.

I have tried also ojupdate custom event, but the same problem.
I have tried event change when item is null, but no success.

What i want to do is when deleting the value from the item (when item is null) to trigger an action.

Is there a DA that can help me on this particular issue?

```
Item: P37_ART
Type: Text field with autocomplete
Settings: Contains & Ignore Case
          Lazy Loading: YES
          Maximum values in List: 20 
Item based on SQL Query and the format is number1||' - '||text1
Example:  1245 - Groceries



Dynamic Action:
Event: Update [Text field with autocomplete]
Action: Execute Javascript code 
        alert('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

create another dynamic action thats has client side condition type javascript condition and check if your Text field is empty or is null using JS code, for example:

```
document.getElementById("textfield").value == "" || document.getElementById("textfield").value.length == 0 || document.getElementById("textfield").value== null
```